# Include caption underneath post images

Tags: images, captions

Hello I've been struggling for ages trying to find a solution for this. Basically I just want to retrieve all images from a post and display a caption underneath. Here is the code i'm using:

```
    <?php
$argsThumb = array(
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => null
);
$attachments = get_posts($argsThumb);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo '<div class="slideshow-content"><img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', false, false).'" /><div class="captions"><p>'.apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title).'</p></div></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see it currently displays the title, but not the caption. I have tried using: $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt; - but not exactly sure where to implement it and what I have tried doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why `$attachment->post_excert;` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

the following should just show the caption:

```
echo '<div class="slideshow-content"><img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', false, false).'" /><div class="captions">'.apply_filters('the_excerpt', $attachment->post_excerpt).'</div></div>';
```

(applying the excerpt filter adds the paragraph tag automatically)

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's fixed it. The only problem I have is that when first uploading an image and a caption is entered it displays fine. However, if upload without a caption & then edit the post and image caption, it won't display. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Actually, no worries I have solved it. Editing the caption from the gallery works, but not from within the post editor!

Comment: There's no way to access the Post Editor for Attachment post-types. As far as I know, you have to use the Media Manager. The "caption" field correlates to `$post->post_excerpt` for the *Attachment* itself. The Post Editor applies to the excerpt for the *Parent Post* to which the images are attached.

Comment: Of course - that's why it wasn't updating output! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In what context are you attempting to run this code?

If it's inside the Loop (e.g. within another Post), why not just use `[gallery id="123"]`?

If it's outside the Loop (or outside the Post content), why not use `do_shortcode( 'gallery', $args )`?

Comment: I'm running it inside the loop in single.php. I need to load images with <div class="slideshow-content"> wrapped around for a slideshow. Is this also possible with the method you mentioned?

Comment: Is this slideshow going to appear in *every* Post, or just selected Posts. If only in *selected* Posts: how are you implementing the selection?

Comment: Currently it is every post - as I am creating the theme to be used as a portfolio. However - I may separate it later by category - I'm assuming something like this would work?

<?php 
if ( in_category( 'slideshow' )) {
// do slideshow
} else {
 // other
}
?>